# Is my lighting correct for a bearded dragon?

Tags: reptiles, bearded-dragon, equipment, terrariums, lighting

I currently have only one light source going at a time, during the day I place the UVB light in the lamp while at night I insert the infrared basking light.

It is 75 °F (24 °C) where the UVB light is, though sometimes she will sit there with her mouth open.

Comment: Can you post photos of your setup?

Comment: it will not let me send the picture for some reason but she has already ate 9 crickets she ate some kiwi yesterday but she will not eat any spinach leaves he has licked a tomato but that is it can you give me any advice. and how many crickets can she eat daily?

Comment: no worries, can you also add the brand and wattage of lights  you use?

Comment: I take her everywhere with me i work at a tire shop shes outside alot so i think shes fine but and im getting a different basking light now it freaking broke but the brand for the UVB  is Boshi its both UVB and UVA she loves it and it doesnt say the wattage size but it last for 4 months. And also he pet store didnt freaking know how old she is so im guessing shes a month old but she wont eat any veggies or drink any water does that mean shes sick?

Answer (score 3):

Reptiles need to thermoregulate so you should always have a daytime basking light along with the tube UVB light for the cooler end. Mercury vapor bulbs or metal halide bulbs for basking are the strongest for UV output as well as heat for basking.

Some metal halides have hot spots (essential areas with too high UV output), Zoo-Med products are the way to go for safety.

1) [PowerSun - Metal Halide](https://zoomed.com/powersun-h-i-d-metal-halide-uvb-lamp-fixture/)

2) [SolarGlo - Mercury Vapor Bulb](http://www.exo-terra.com/en/products/solar_glo.php)

The cooler end should have fluorescent tube lighting, this will give UV for the full length of the enclosure.

1) [ReptiSun T5 HO 10.0](https://zoomed.com/t5-ho-reptisun-10-0-uvb/)

All of these lights emit UV rays for 1 year and should be replaced. You will have to adjust distance of the lights depending on how tall his enclosure is as they need to be a certain distance away to prevent over-exposure.

Coil bulbs are not sufficient enough for UV production for bearded dragons, they need high output lighting.

I would not turn on any lights for night time as it interrupts their sleep cycles, to keep his enclosure warm at night use a ceramic heat emitter or install undertank heating cables (**only to be used with a thermostat**).

For more information on bearded dragon care you can view the following questions:

[Diet and care for Bearded Dragon](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15224/diet-and-care-for-bearded-dragon?rq=1)

[What is a good substrate for a bearded dragon terrarium?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2285/what-is-a-good-substrate-for-a-bearded-dragon-terrarium?rq=1)

[Why are red bulbs bad for my bearded dragon?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/why-are-red-bulbs-bad-for-my-bearded-dragon)

[How do I tell the sex of a bearded dragon?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5923/how-do-i-tell-the-sex-of-a-bearded-dragon)